# real time data: Nextjs + SWR

Tags: next.js13, swr

I am working on a project where I need information to be displayed in real time. For this, I am using nextjs and swr. By copying the examples provided at https://swr.vercel.app/es-ES/examples/ssr I am not able to display data on the screen. Can someone give me some light?

I created a new project with:

```
npx create-next-app --example hello-world hello-world-app
```

I copied the source from SWR Vercel web and nothing it has happened.

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "swr-ssr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "post-update": "yarn upgrade --latest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "swr": "2.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

And my index.js is:

```
import useSWR, { SWRConfig } from "swr";

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
const API = "https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/swr";

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const repoInfo = await fetcher(API);
  return {
    props: {
      fallback: {
        [API]: repoInfo
      }
    }
  };
}

function Repo() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(API);

  // there should be no `undefined` state
  console.log("Is data ready?", !!data);

  if (error) return "An error has occurred.";
  if (!data) return "Loading...";
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>{data.description}</p>
      <strong> {data.subscribers_count}</strong>{" "}
      <strong>✨ {data.stargazers_count}</strong>{" "}
      <strong> {data.forks_count}</strong>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App({ fallback }) {
  return (
    <SWRConfig value={{ fallback }}>
      <Repo />
    </SWRConfig>
  );
}
```

Comment: You forgot to pass `fetcher` to the `useSWR` hook